# Trying to get music to play as soon as program starts

Tags: python, pygame

Where does my music section belong in this code to play upon starting? If i put it before the loop it only plays the music, if i put it during the loop the program will not run. I think what is happening is that the music doesnt have a chance to play because the loop just keeps restarting. Thanks

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("doommusic.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(1090)
pygame.mixer.music.stop()




#imports pygame library
import pygame
import sys
import time

pygame.init()

#Sceen height and width
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

#color variables
white = (255,255,255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Operation Python')

screen.fill(white)

Fps = pygame.time.Clock()

man1x = 200
man1y = 200
man=100
man1=100

#main loop
while True:
screen.fill(white)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()

pygame.draw.circle(screen,(9, 44, 100),(man1x,man1y),25)
pygame.draw.circle(screen,(9, 44, 100),(man,man1),75)

pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    man1x -= 1
if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    man1x += 1
if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
    man1y -= 1
if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    man1y += 1

pygame.display.flip()
Fps.tick(120)
```

Comment: you cannot use `time.sleep(1090)` for this purpose, this makes your game pause

Comment: I deleted that line and put the code back in the loop, now the program runs but the music does not play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this line, it will wait until the music ends

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("doommusic.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()  

#main loop
while True:
    [...]
```

Comment: Well that was simple....thank you. I guess I'm just not understanding why after you "load" and "play" (-1) why it doesnt just play the music and move onto my main loop?

Comment: i was testing some examples, you can also use only `pygame.mixer.music.load("doommusic.mp3")`,
`pygame.mixer.music.play(1) ` by default the loop parameter is 0, i think this is confusing [(doc)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play)

Comment: What's the purpose of `pygame.event.wait()`?

Comment: ^^^same question. pygame,mixer.music.play(1) loops the track, what does "wait" do?

Comment: this is an experimental remainder :p . but the loop parameter is weird, `play(1) ` plays only once, but `play(2)` plays 3 loops....

Comment: and (-1) plays over and over...weird

Comment: Yeah, that confused me once as well.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately following the pygame.init() you need to add

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("doommusic.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: although it worked without having it right after, I get why you said this,